# How can I make a bash script case insensitive?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, case-sensitive

I'm writing a script that will output something about my friends depending on what name they input, but in the script I put the conditions for the if/then as their names capitalized. Is there a way I can make it so they can put in a lower case letter and it still be the same output?

Comment: Please [edit] and add the relevant part of your script to the question

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Here is a reference for almost everything you want to know about bash enjoy `https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In bash, you can use the `,,` parameter expansion to lowercase a variable value:

```
#! /bin/bash

read -p Name: name
case ${name,,} in
    (john) echo Hi John! ;;
    (jane) echo Hallo Jane! ;;
    (jack) echo Long time no see, Jack! ;;
    (*)    echo "I don't know you." ;;
esac
```

Comment: Any particular reason you did not close the question as a dup; and instead chose to answer? There are lots apparent dups: [bash script case insensitive](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+script+case+insensitive). It appears to be very poor leadership by example.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use words with all capital letters as cases, an example:

```
# name="Viktor"; echo "${name^^}"
VIKTOR
```

So, just write something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Type your name"
read name
capitalName=$(echo "${name^^}")
case "${capitalName}" in
...
esac
```

Comment: `capitalName=${name^^}` is sufficient; there's no need for a command substitution here.